# QGIS Versioning plugin

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins

I have created a database from QGIS Cloud free account. I have added a Post GIS layer into QGIS desktop. i have installed versioning plugin and added a group. After Selecting a Group when Hostorize the following error message pop out. how to fix this?

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_versioning\versioningDB\utils.py", line 94, in execute
    self.cur.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "versioning_constraints" already exists
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_versioning\plugin.py", line 940, in historize
    versioning.historize(self.pg_conn_info(), schema)
  File "C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_versioning\versioningDB\versioning.py", line 64, in historize
    pcur.execute(sql.format(schema=schema))
  File "C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_versioning\versioningDB\utils.py", line 97, in execute
    sys.stderr.write(traceback.format_exc())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.6.0-Noosa Noosa, 58734527ab 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\bin
C:\Users\parul Jain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\parul Jain\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
C:/Users/parul Jain/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_versioning
.
C:\Users\parul Jain\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\QRealTime
```